# How to get all the videos of a YouTube channel with the Yt gem?

Tags: ruby, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to use the [Yt gem](http://fullscreen.github.io/yt/) to get all the videos of channel. I configure the gem with my YouTube Data API key.

Unfortunately when I use it it returns a maximum of ~1000 videos, even for channels having more than 1000 videos. `Yt::Channel#video_count` returns the correct number of videos.

```rb
channel = Yt::Channel.new id: "UCGwuxdEeCf0TIA2RbPOj-8g"
channel.video_count           # => 1845
channel.videos.map(&:id).size # => 949
```

The Youtube API can't be set to return more than 50 items per request, so I guess Yt automatically performs several requests going through each next page of results to be able to return more than 50 results.

For some reason though it does not go through all the result pages. I don't see a way in Yt for me to control how it goes through the pages of results. In particular I could not find a way to force it to get a single page of results, access the returned value `nextPageToken`, in order to perform a new request with this value.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into gem's /spec folder, you can see a test for your code.

```
 describe 'when the channel has more than 500 videos' do
   let(:id) { 'UC0v-tlzsn0QZwJnkiaUSJVQ' }

   specify 'the estimated and actual number of videos can be retrieved' do
     # @note: in principle, the following three counters should match, but
     #   in reality +video_count+ and +size+ are only approximations.
     expect(channel.video_count).to be > 500
     expect(channel.videos.size).to be > 500
   end
end
```

I did some tests and what I have noticed it that: video_count is the number that is displayed on youtube next to channel's name. This value is not accurate. Not rly sure what it represents.

If you do `channel.videos.size`, the number is not accurate either, because the videos collection can contain some empty(?) records.

If you do `channel.videos.map(&:id).size` the returned value should be correct. By correct I mean it should equal to number of videos listed at:

> https://www.youtube.com/channel/:channel_id/videos

Comment: Thanks but I've just counted the number of videos listed in https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGwuxdEeCf0TIA2RbPOj-8g/videos (I've clicked on 'load more' until all the videos were displayed) and it exactly matches `channel.video_count` actually (1845). So I'm back at the state where `channel.videos` does not seem to return all the channel videos.

Comment: You are right. Should have tested your case more precisely. From what I have read it turns out that YT API is limited to max 1k records. That would mostly explain why that gem can not return all the videos as it exceeds the limit.